# Plot simple graph given 4 vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Draw a graph with the specified properties or show (prove) that no such graph exists:

A simple graph with four vertices of degrees 1, 1, 3, and 3

```
Maximum number of edges = nC2 (where n is the number of vertices)
                        = 4(4-1)/2
                        = 6

Total degree = 1 + 1 + 3 +3 = 8
Number of edges this graph have = 8/2 = 4
```

Theoritically, this graph should be possible but I'm having trouble drawing this graph. I always end up with 3 vertices having a degree of 2 each and the other vertex having a degree of 1, so I'm not really not sure what I'm supposed to do here.

Comment: It is possible if the graph is a [multigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph)

Comment: As Henry already pointed out, if you allow multiple edges between vertices and disconnected graphs, there are multiple such graphs exist.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are two vertices of degree $3$ there are two vertices adjacent to all the other vertices.  Then the other two vertices are adjacent to both of these, so there is no vertex of degree $1$.

No such graph exists.